# How should I design my Play2 java application so that complies with the "Play2 thinking"

Tags: java, playframework-2.1

I'm building a Play2 application with Java that will receive a couple of phone numbers and post it to a rest service that sends SMS.

I have created a Controller and I'm thinking that the controller will handle the request, perform the unmarshalling to a Java list. Then I was thinking of creating a SmsService class to handle the calling. What I can't understand is how I should implement this in a Play2 manner.

Do I, in the Controller, instantiate the SmsService by typing new? Or do i use
dependency injection? Maybe I'm to colored by my Spring background, forget all about
injection and write everything in the Controller? Maybe make the method static
and use the SmsService like SmsService.sendSms(numbers)

I have checked the samples that follow with the 2.1 folder of Play2 but the examples there
do not handle this case. I have probably missed something in the documentation.

How would you do this and why?

**Sms Controller:**

```
public class Sms extends Controller {

    private static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();        

    @BodyParser.Of(value = BodyParser.Json.class)
    public static Result inviteToReview() {
        ObjectNode result = Json.newObject();

        JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();
        if(json == null) {
            result.put("status", "KO");
            result.put("message", "Missing phone number list [phone_numbers]");
            return badRequest(result);
        }

        List<String> numbers = new ArrayList<String>();    
        TypeReference collectionType = new TypeReference<ArrayList<String>>() {
        };
        try {
            numbers = mapper.readValue(json.get("phone_numbers"), collectionType);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // handle error
        }

        SmsService smsService = new SmsService();
        result = smsService.sendSms(numbers);
        return ok(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I got now answers I did it like this.

Global:

```
public class Global extends GlobalSettings {

    private static final Injector INJECTOR = createInjector();  

   /**
     * Need for injection.
     *
     * @param controllerClass
     * @param <A>
     * @return
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Override
    public <A> A getControllerInstance(Class<A> controllerClass) throws Exception {
        return INJECTOR.getInstance(controllerClass);
    }

    private static Injector createInjector() {
        return Guice.createInjector();
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class Sms extends Controller {

    private static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Inject
    private SmsService smsService;

    @BodyParser.Of(value = BodyParser.Json.class)
    public Result invite(){
        ObjectNode result = Json.newObject();
        smsService.sendSms(new ArrayList<String>());
        result.put("status", "OK");
        //cool stuff ehere
        return ok(result);
    }
}
```

routes:

```
GET /sms/invite    @controllers.Sms.invite()
```

Build:

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
      javaCore,
    "com.google.inject" % "guice" % "3.0",    
  )
```